# Where to find descriptions of the example ESP32 sketches in the Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I chose this one at random

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/HelloServer/HelloServer.ino

but looked at the code of others & hope that there is some description of these sketches, as the comments in the code are somewhat sparse.

Answer (score -1):

If the description is written as comments in code you can find it there itself. Description of examples will not be written in seperate files

Comment: What a pity, as the comments are insufficient to understand the projects :-(

Answer (score -1):

ESP32 is a well-structured microcontroller. Before using it, I would recommend you to use basic Arduino Uno/Mega and get yourself well-versed with the programming concepts. So then afterwards when you switch to ESP32, you won't need descriptions to help you through the code. But still if some part of the code is not understandable, I'll prefer you to google the functions and read about them.

And the descriptions of the codes are not as such provided anywhere, except the ones important are mentioned in the code files.